# Print by browser and export to image file

Tags: javascript, html, css, printing, export

This is really good for exporting to PDF file.
[image]
Are there a way to use its content to export to PNG or JPG file?

Or others way to export to PNG?

Please advise best way for me.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible. If you're a Windows user, I advise you to use Snipping Tool to save your display to a file, or just Print Screen and paste to Paint.

Comment: yup, that's really good way. however, I need to export directly to PNG for my case. that should be a button to click then save as picture file. using as the same css for printing.